# Auto Refresh Mechanism in Apache Tomcat Server

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin

I am Developing a web application in [vaadin](https://vaadin.com) and it is also on the production server. The application present on the production server is used by multiple users at the same time and can make changes at the same time. Now when one user changes certain data in the application, the other users should be aware of the changes made by this user, so that the application runs smoothly. I used "Push" mechanism to update all instances connected to the server. but some time it gives concurrent modification exception so "pusher" is not working for me in all cases. is there other mechanism free of concurrent modification exceptions when there is a change in your data server will notify the browser which in turn will display the new data to all the users connected to the server.

Comment: What vaadin version are you using?
Are you propertly synching/locking the instances wher you modify the Vaadin UI Elements?

Comment: vaadin 6 , i used synchronized keywords but it is not working perfectly

Comment: Have you some stack trace?
Is it throwing it in the vaadin code or in one of your own classes?

Vaadin 7 is much more robust for such stuff...

Comment: the exception occurs in vaadin own implemented class. e.g modifying table at the same time by multiple users causes exception. and table is vaadin component.

Comment: I think you need Vaadin 7 at least, at servlet 3.0 compatible server.

Comment: our application is too huge and it is made in vaadin 6. so it will take a lot of time to convert our app to vaadin 7. so is there a way that works in vaadin 6?. or is there  easiest way to convert vaadin 6 app to vaadin 7?.